# How to get the nodeset.xml of an OPC UA server?

Tags: opc, opc-ua

Is there a way to use an OPC UA client application that connects to a specific endpoint and allows me to download the nodeset.xml of the host OPC UA server?

I want to get the nodeset information to be able to rebuild/modify the host server.

Answer (score 2):

I found a library that does exactly that:
https://github.com/plt-tud/opc_ua_xml_export_client

Answer (score 1):

The standard `Server` Object has an *optional* `Namespaces` component which may have one or more HasComponent references to `NamespaceMetadataType` objects, one per namespace. These objects in turn have an *optional* `NamespaceFile` file member of `AddressSpaceFileType` that you can access via standard `FileType` methods, if it exists. (See OPC UA Part 5 for more info)

That said... most servers do not have these Nodes present or otherwise offer the ability to arbitrarily get the namespace XML, you will probably have to recursively browse the AddressSpace and create one yourself in most cases.